# How to append source html to a DOMElement in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, appendchild

Is there a way of appending source html into a DOMElement? Something like this:

```
$trElement->appendSource("<a href='?select_user=4'>Username</a>");
```

It would parse that fragment and then append it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for

[- `DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML` — Append raw XML data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php)

Example from Manual:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML("<root/>");
$f = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML("<foo>text</foo><bar>text2</bar>");
$doc->documentElement->appendChild($f);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: Note: Your HTML input must also be valid XML otherwise you will get errors. The way I have done this is to create another document, load the HTML into that (as HTML, not XML) and then deep-import the newly created nodes back into my original document.

Comment: In case you'll get `output conversion failed due to conv error` on `DOMDocument::saveHTML()` as result of adding external code, you need to force conversion to specific encoding standard e.g. via `utf8_encode()`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have a reference to the [document root](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in scope, you can always access it via the [`ownerDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.ownerdocument) property of an arbitrary node:

```
$frag = $trElement->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
$frag->appendXML("<a href='?select_user=4'>Username</a>");
$trElement->appendChild($frag);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this with [`DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php):

```
$fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<a href="select_user=4">Username</a>');
$element->appendChild($fragment);
```

In this case, it would be simpler to do it with a normal [`createElement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) call:

```
$el = $dom->createElement('a', 'Username');
$el->setAttribute('href', 'select_user=4');
$element->appendChild($el);
```

In each case, `$element` is the DOM element to which you want to append your code.

Comment: "In this case, it would be simpler to do it with a normal createElement call:", this is not my case since in my app I can have an arbitrary input so the fragment is ok for this.