# Having Two HTML issues with PHP DOM: 1.) DOMDocument::createEntityReference $name values and 2.) how to add multiple CSS classes an element?

Tags: php, html, css, dom, domdocument

Working with PHP DOM - HTML manipulation.

Got 2 questions

1. Recently read that, there is better way to output special html characters (e.g. ©): [`DOMDocument::createEntityReference()` method](http://php.net/domdocument.createentityreference). Main advantage is, you don't need to use `htmlentities`, it will be automatically escaped.
   For ex: `$copyright_symbol = $document->createEntityReference("copy");`. 
   Now, the problem is, where can I find characters' code reference? In my case I need php equalent of `&#215;` (× symbol)
2. What if I want to set muliple classes to element? Can I do it like that `$el->setAttribute('class', 'class1 class2 ...')` ??

Comment: You can find a PHP array of [all named HTML entities in this answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11179875/367456). Like the PHP manual says, use them without the starting `&` and ending `;` for `DOMDocument::createEntityReference()`.

Comment: At Stackoverflow, **one question at a time**, or eventually a question and a sub-question. `setAttribute` is not a subquestion of `createEntityReference`. PS: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13808846/287948) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13849787/287948) about multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) you can see character codes as well as friendly names. For your &#215, you will use "times"
 and for the second question, yes, you can do it like that.

Comment: One more q: Can I append multiple elements at once?

Comment: as far as I know, you will have to perform createElement and then appendChild and if you want to do it for multiple elements, you should do it in a loop...or you can append prepared html as described in this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751437/php-dom-append-source-html-to-a-domelement

Comment: There are a possibility of express [numeric entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) with another DOMDocument method?