# How to append text to external html file inside of a specific tag using PHP?

Tags: php, html, string, append

Lets say i have an external html page and I want to append text inside of a specific tag from my php admin page such as putting miscellaneous text inside of this span tag.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<span class="text"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I do that with PHP? I'm trying to make an admin page for this website, and I need to append text inside of certain tags. I don't even know where to start with this, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Like file_get_content, or include?

Comment: @itsme I think what he means is, he wants to open a file, write/append to it within a specific tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append source html to a DOMElement in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751437/how-to-append-source-html-to-a-domelement-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using PHP's DOMDocument, like so:

```
// Load the HTML document
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHtmlFile( 'htmlpage.html');

// Get the parent node where you want the insertion to occur
$parent = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item( 0);

// Create the child element 
$child = $doc->createElement( 'span');
$child->setAttribute( 'class', 'text');

// Append (insert) the child to the parent node
$parent->appendChild( $child);

// Save the resulting HTML
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

So, given this HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The [resulting HTML would be](http://viper-7.com/uLo4bJ):

```
<html>
<body>
<span class="text"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

(Neglecting the DOCTYPE declaration that DOMDocument adds if it is not present)

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot man... if i was getting paid a decent amount for this site i would give you something... very helpful thanks

Comment: hmm, my only problem with this is switching from getElementsByTagName to getElementById... it gives me php errors

Comment: thanks a lot. still have problems with elementbyid but i can use tagname for this application.

Comment: @JohnJohnson According to a commenter in the PHP Docs, if your HTML page doesnt' specify a doctype then `getElementById` will always return null. (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you need this for, you may be able to do this another way -- make that target .HTML file into a .PHP file instead, with it filling in the appropriate content itself using, let's say, a function called `get_span_contents()`, like so:

```
<html>
<body>
  <span class="text">
    <?PHP get_span_contents(); ?>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

One downside is that this will be generated for every request of the document (potentially, depending on caching schemes), whereas if you separated it into two steps (1. Write out the HTML, 2. Serve the HTML separately) you would only ever be doing the generation once.  Depending on how dynamic the content is, or how minor the computation cost, that might not be a problem.

Comment: thanks, this is a good option if i cannot figure out the DOMDocument