# Need a help on PHP domDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to append some text to divs which has same class.

```
$dom = new DOMdocument();  
$dom->formatOutput = true;

@$dom->loadHTMLFile('first.html');    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom)

$after = new DOMText('Newly appended text');

$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@class="mix"]');

foreach($elements as $element)

    {

        $element->appendChild($after);      
        //echo $dom->saveHTML();
    }

$dom->saveHTMLFile('first.html');
```

But when I open first.html, The appended text is only appeded to last div of above class.
If I uncomment saveHTML() then it shows perfect result. Just problem after saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot append the same DOM node to multiple points in the tree, which is what you are doing here. You need to create a separate (but identical) node each time:

```
foreach($elements as $element)
{
    $after = new DOMText('Newly appended text'); // moved this inside the loop
    $element->appendChild($after);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jon, could you tell me that how to append any random html code? Eg, $after = new DOMText('<div>append</div>');  
or $after = new DOMText('<script>alert('Hi')</script>');
The content will be normal text or html or even php script.

Comment: @AmitS: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751437/php-dom-append-source-html-to-a-domelement

Comment: yeah I saw it. Its working. The small bug is that if I want to add php code eg, <?php echo $x; ?> then it just removed '?' from end of php.
Anyways thanks.