# How to print unescaped HTML with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, html

I have a simple, locally-run app in JQuery & PHP that allows a user to open a file, rearrange it's DOM elements, and then generate a new file with the rearranged elements. The problem is that the PHP DOMDocument is printing escaped HTML. I need to print the contents of `#newfile`, received by the POST as `$content`, as unescaped HTML.

The POST function looks like this:

```
   $("#submit").click(function() {
     var str = $('#newfile').html();
     $.post("generate.php", { content: str} );
  });
```

The generate.php file looks like this:

```
 <?php
 $content = $_POST['content'];

 $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');

 $doc->formatOutput = true;

 $root = $doc->createElement('html');
 $root = $doc->appendChild($root);

 $head = $doc->createElement('head');
 $head = $root->appendChild($head);

 $body = $doc->createElement('body');
 $body = $root->appendChild($body);

 $element = $doc->createElement('div', $content);
 $element = $body->appendChild($element);

 echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->saveHTMLFile("output/test.html") . ' bytes';

 ?>
```

The output is currently a well-formatted HTML document, but the content I need is escaped:

```
 <html>
 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
 <body><div>
        &lt;div class="page"&gt;
            &lt;h3&gt;1. Definition&lt;/h3&gt;
            &lt;div id="definition" class="output ui-droppable"&gt;
            &lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;/div&gt;
 </div></body></html>
```

How do I print $content as unescaped HTML?

Answer (score 0):

`html_entity_decode()` is the opposite of htmlentities() in that it converts all HTML entities in the string to their applicable characters.

```
    <?php
    $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

    $a = htmlentities($orig);

    $b = html_entity_decode($a);

    echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now

    echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now
    ?>
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/html_entity_decode

Comment: Can you suggest how to incorporate this into the DOMDocument so that the value of $content is printed unescaped? I've tried it with your construction above, and it makes no difference- it still prints escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I used the method [shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4751503/844668)- createDocumentFragment + appendXML. My final generate.php looks like this, and works perfectly:

```
<?php
$content = $_POST['content'];

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('html');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$head = $doc->createElement('head');
$head = $root->appendChild($head);

$body = $doc->createElement('body');
$body = $root->appendChild($body);

$f = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$f->appendXML($content);
$body->appendChild($f);

echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->saveHTMLFile("output/test.html") . ' bytes'; // Wrote: 129 bytes

?>
```